# How to use type-safe struct type Core Data attributes with mogenerator?

Tags: ios, core-data, mogenerator

For attributes of struct types that NSKeyValueCoding can handle, I use the Core Data accessor pattern described in Apple's docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW14).

For example, an NSRange struct can be specified in the Core Data model as of type Transformable, then the NSValue rigmarole can be avoided for clients by providing accessors in an NSManagedObject subclass of the form:

**Interface:**

```
@property(assign, nonatomic) NSRange range;
```

**Implementation;**

```
- (NSRange) range {

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"range"];
    NSRange retVal = range;
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"range"];

    return retVal;
}

- (void)setRange:(NSRange)aRange {

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"range"];
    range = aRange;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"range"];
}
```

Mogenerator's generated NSManagedObject subclasses, however, declare Transformable attributes as NSObject properties, so clients need to get/set NSValues.

What's the best way to handle this situation with mogenerator, whilst (1) keeping with the simple Transformable pattern rather than messing with transient backing attributes, and (2) avoiding any edits of Mogenerator's 'machine' classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate way to deal with this would be, as scc suggested in the previously accepted answer, to change the mogenerator template files. They would need to (a) change the transformable attribute's accessor to be of the appropriate type (NSRange in this instance) and then (b) add the accessors with the appropriate KVO method calls.

As that's more than I have time right now to figure out how to do, my temporary expedient is as follows:

- add an attributeValueClassName key to the attribute's userInfo dict (in the Core Data editor), with the value NSValue (just to make sure the generator's accessors will be NSValue rather than NSObject).
- in the human-editable mogenerator output, add accessors like those in the question, except with a new name  (eg. rangeValue and setRangeValue). The underlying values will still be the persisted NSValues, but my accessors take care of the KVO and boxing/unboxing.

Not ideal, but I do get strongly-typed accessors without having to edit the mogenerator machine files.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type from `NSObject` to whatever type you need after the model object generator has finished its job. You should not have any compiler warnings after that.

BTW, when I run the managed object model generator after defining a transformable attribute I do not get `NSObject` but `id`. No warnings.

Comment: I could do that, but I want to avoid editing mogenerator's machine .h files.

Comment: On the NSObject vs id thing -- different mogenerator versions, maybe? Mine's 1.24

Answer (score 0):

Can you alter the template files that mogenerator uses? (I think) that provided you stay away from scalar values, you can safely use `NSObject *` instead of `id`.

Comment: Of course this is the way to handle it. What was I (not) thinking? I'll have a look into the template format and post some notes back here on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For those willing to edit the machine template file, use the following conditional to special case for the transformable NSRange attribute.

```
<$if Attribute.hasTransformableAttributeType && Attribute.objectAttributeClassName == "NSRange" $>
```

Here's how I changed my machine template header file. https://gist.github.com/2414047

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the wrong part of the documentation.  Please look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html):

`NSRange` doesn't need to be transformed.  There are methods for all those basic structures, such as:

```
NSRangeFromString();
NSStringFromRange();
```

So you would define the shadow property as something like "`rangeAsString`" of type `NSString`.

In your MO subclass you would follow in the docs on how to properly convert and store the value so that core data knows your object became dirty when doing like:

```
myObject.range = NSMakeRange(0,5);
```

Comment: Using NSValue's NSKeyValueCoding implementation is simpler than using shadow attributes. There may be other tradeoffs involved between the approaches, but I don't know what they would be.

Comment: I'm open to corrections.  Core Data is certainly a large and confusing framework and I'm not 100% versed on all the ways to extend it.  Are you saying your above code will actually tie into undo management or are you only posting half of your solution?  You also have primitiveRange and setPrimitiveRange:?

Comment: I don't make use of undo management, but AFAI understand, all the context needs for undo is that attribute access triggers KVO notifications (which the above code does). I haven't implemented or invoked the primitive accessors, and I'm frankly not clear on the relationship between the managed object accessors and the ivar in this case. But it is the pattern recommended in the Core Data guide for NSRange attributes (see the end of [this section](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW14))